# Как вывести сообщение что нужно авторизоваться

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
function my_product_query( $q ) {
$is_logged_in = is_user_logged_in();
$cat = 'categorie-1';

if ( !$is_logged_in ) {
    $q->set( 'tax_query',
        array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'sex',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    );
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'my_product_query', 10, 1 );
```

Данный код запрещает просмотр категории sex без авторизации. Как вывести сообщение что нужно авторизоваться?
Сейчас выводит
"Товаров, соответствующих вашему запросу, не обнаружено."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь попробовать **wc_print_notice** или через аякс, насильно вывести форму авторизации.
У меня wc_print_notice используется, если человек в корзину положил недостаточно товаров (минимальная сумма покупки).